# Can't configurate associations in Entity Framework 5 with MySql Code First.

Tags: mysql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Doing this same example:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx

```
public class Order {
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
    public virtual OrderBilling Billing { get; set; }
}

public class OrderBilling {
    public int OrderBillingId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderBilling> OrderBilling { get; set; }

public class OrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order> {
    public OrderConfiguration() {
    HasRequired(o => o.Billing)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
}
}
```

Works perfectly fine in Microsoft SQL.
but when executing on MySQL it creates the tables and somewhere in the generation (i think when applying the FK's) it's throws a :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (OrderId)
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION' at line 3
```

Im using connector 6.6.5 and Entity Framework 5.

Is this a problem with connector? With approach? Should I add some MySql configuration to support this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because using Order as a Table Name and in the SQL sentence there's one place where it doesn't use ´order´.

Changed table name to SalesOrder and everything started to work flawlessly again.